# Attack on home dir encryption with sddm pam_mount by using password in /etc/shadow

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, file-encryption

I'm using Debian + sddm + KDE with **ONLY** home directory encrypted with `gocryptfs`.

Decrypting is performed with gocryptfs as follows:

- PC boots as usual and starts the sddm service
- I enter my login credentials (which equal to my encryption password)
- pam_mount decrypts and mounts my user's directory, and performs the login.
  I know, my password [is hashed and salted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37050/where-is-my-password-stored-on-linux), so it cannot be restored without rather much effort.

My questions are:

- In case of physical access by attacker, how [hashed and salted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37050/where-is-my-password-stored-on-linux), but unencrypted password affects user's directory data security?
- How much easier is to bruteforce password for encrypted data?
- Are there any new attack vectors, since that password can be found in the `/etc/shadow` file?